# Magento 2: How to get product custom attribute in product grid

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, product-collection, custom-attributes, product-grid

How to get product custom attribute in product grid. I have create product attribute as "qty_per_box". But it is not showing in collection.

The following code is not getting custom product attribue.

```
  /**
    * @return Grid
    */
        protected function _prepareCollection()
        {
            $collection = $this->productFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect("*");
            $this->setCollection($collection);
            return parent::_prepareCollection();
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

**1/ Magento Admin > Stores > Attributes / Product > Click on your custom attribute > Advanced Attribute Properties > Set "Add to Column Options" to "Yes" and click on "Save attribute" button**

[image]

**2/ Magento Admin > Products > Inventory / Catalog > Select your custom attribute on "Columns box"**

[image]

Comment: I am showing product grid in custom module. I have created product attribute as swatch option. In product gird it is returning the option value. But I want to get option text.